# adding and removing items in xml list

Tags: c#, xml, logging, serialization

I have created a little logg program and with this i can save custom classes to xml, and convert them back from xml to a class. this works fine, but the problem is if i want to add one class to the list in the xml, i have to read all of them, add one class and rewrite all of them if i use this method, now i know i can manualy add a class by searching for elements and so on, but i wondered if i could do this in the way that i write all of them.

this is an example of the code that i ame using:

```
public static void Test()
    {
        List<LoggInformation> infos = new List<LoggInformation>();

        infos.Add(new LoggInformation() { Level = BpuInterface.BpuInterface.BPUController.LoggLevel.Debug, Message = "error1" });

        infos.Add(new LoggInformation() { Level = BpuInterface.BpuInterface.BPUController.LoggLevel.Error, Message = "error2" });

        DataContractSerializer dd = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<LoggInformation>));

        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"C://testLoggfile.xml"))
        {
            dd.WriteObject(writer.BaseStream, infos);
        }
    }

    public static void AddOneItem()
    {
        //??????????
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class LoggInformation
    {
        [DataMemberAttribute]
        public BpuInterface.BpuInterface.BPUController.LoggLevel Level { get; set; }

        [DataMemberAttribute]
        public Source Source { get; set; }

        [DataMemberAttribute]
        public string ExceptionMessage { get; set; }

        [DataMemberAttribute]
        public string ExceptionStack { get; set; }

        [DataMemberAttribute]
        public string ThreadName { get; set; }

        [DataMemberAttribute]
        public System.Threading.ApartmentState ThreadApartmentState { get; set; }

        [DataMemberAttribute]
        public string Message { get; set; }

        [DataMemberAttribute]
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: To maintain a valid XML, you will have to read it all first. So: why XML, could you tolerate an invalid XML, ...

Comment: @HenkHolterman, i dont need xml if there is somthing else that i could use to store serialized objects and then convert tem back to objects when i need them, is there a better way? I need to store objects one by one and get them back as an entiere list of objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this instead `new StreamWriter(@"C://testLoggfile.xml"), true)` will append line at the end of file.

```
 public static void Test()
    {
...
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"C://testLoggfile.xml"), true) // this will append line at the end of file.
        {
            dd.WriteObject(writer.BaseStream, infos);
        }
    }
...
```

Comment: _"will append line at the end of file"_  Yes, and that will produce invalid XML.

Comment: @HenkHolterman not if he is writing without master wrapper, and if he does he can change to not to have one, in log it would not serve any purpose anyway.

Comment: @LIUFA, but there still is a wrapper on all of them for the data beeing a list of objects, so when appending it will still append it after the list, and if i write all objects seperate, then i cant get all the items once to a list of objects